# Fetch first two elements from map

Tags: c++, iterator, stdmap

I have to read only the first two elements from an `std::map`.

Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    map<int,int> a;
    map<int,int>:: iterator itr;
    itr = a.begin();
    cout<<itr->first<<" "<<itr->second<<endl;
    next(itr);
    cout<<itr->first<<" "<<itr->second<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> `next` was not declared in the scope

what am I missing here and if there is a better way to do it?

Comment: Works for me, with gcc 9. Perhaps you are using an old C++ compiler that does not support c++11?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik : Any alternate solution for this

Comment: `std::advance(iter, 1);`

Comment: Yes. There are other ways to increment iterators. See your C++ textbook for more information, and examples.

Comment: You could do itr++. Also make sure to do checks like itr is still valid, ie., `itr!=a.end()`

Comment: See if you can add a `-std=c++11` or similar to the compiler command line.

Answer (score 2):

For using [std::next](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next), you need to have at least C++11 compliant compiler.

`std::next` returns a new incremented iterator. So, you need to use its return value to get the incremented iterator i.e.:

```
itr = next( itr );
```

Right now, `itr` is pointing to the same element because the return value is not used.

If you meant to increment the `itr` without a new iterator then [std::advance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) is a better candidate here i.e.:

```
std::advance( itr, 1 );
```

If you're using a pre-C++11 compiler then you can use increment operator like this:

```
itr++;
```

Or,

```
++itr;
```

Here's a [live](https://godbolt.org/z/AenaLG) demo.

---

In addition, the map is uninitialized/empty and you're trying to access its elements that are not there and this would result in [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Relevant read:

- [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- [C++: "std::endl" vs "\n"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)

Answer (score 0):

you should use `itr++` to move itr forward to point next set of pairs. and you can access them by `map->first;` and `map->second;`